# Hooking into kset->uevent_ops to get device notification

Tags: notifications, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, udev

Before Linux kernel version 2.6.34,I used to hook into uevent_ops to get the device add/remove notification in init_module of my block device driver.

```
    my_uevent_ops = kset->uevent_ops;

    kset->uevent_ops = my_uevent_ops_callback;
```

Now I want to port my driver to 3.2 ,but the kset->uevent_ops is made constant, so i can't hook into it. Is their any way to get notifications of block device driver in my device driver?
Also can I use notifier chain for block devices ?

Thanks in advance.